# Map scales and area and volume

Tags: measure-theory

What kind of steps I need to prove the following:

If we make a map with given scale then the ratio of areas is the square of scale and the ratio of volumes is the cube of scales.

I mean, that was given in the school but the proof was omitted. So is the proof as simple as we can cover maps by squares and cubes, compute the ratio of volumes and take the infimum of the covering?

Answer (score 0):

It is just as easy to prove a more general statement: if $f:X\to Y$ is a [Lipschitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) map, then for every set $A\subset X$ we have $$\mathcal{H}^d(f(A))\le L^d \mathcal{H}^d(A)\tag{1}$$ where $L$ is the Lipschitz constant of $f$.

The proof goes like this: cover $A$ by some sets $E_j$ so that  $$\sum_j(\operatorname{diam} E_j)^d<  \mathcal{H}^d(A)+\epsilon$$
observe that
$$\sum_j(\operatorname{diam} f(E_j))^d<  L^d\mathcal{H}^d(A)+L^d\epsilon$$
and conclude with (1). (You should also make sure that the diameters of $E_j$ are small, as required by the definition of the Hausdorff measure.)

Now suppose that $f$ is a homothety: all distances are multiplied by $L$ under it. Then $f$ is injective and $f^{-1}$ is Lipschitz (on the range of $f$) with constant $L^{-1}$. Applying (1) to both $f$ and $f^{-1}$, we get 
$$\mathcal{H}^d(f(A)) = L^d \mathcal{H}^d(A)\tag{2}$$